# Typescript Callstack Size Exceeded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

The following code throws a Callstack Size Exceeded Error:

```
    declare var createjs:any;

import {Animation} from '../animation';
import {Events} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

export class FischSuccess extends Animation {



    constructor(@Inject(Events) public events: Events) {
        super(events);
        this.initAnimation();
    }

    initAnimation() {

        var lib, images, ss;

        (function (lib, img, cjs, ss, events) {


            var cjs = createjs;


            var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
            lib.webFontTxtFilters = {};

// library properties:
            lib.properties = {
                width: 1000,
                height: 650,
                fps: 25,
                color: "#FFFFFF",
                opacity: 1.00,
                webfonts: {},
                manifest: [
                    {src:"images/fisch_atlas_success.png", id:"fisch_atlas_"}
                ]
            };



            lib.ssMetadata = [
                {name:"fisch_atlas_", frames: [[158,0,156,110],[0,0,156,110],[316,0,156,110],[0,112,156,110],[158,112,156,110]]}
            ];


            lib.webfontAvailable = function(family) {
                lib.properties.webfonts[family] = true;
                var txtFilters = lib.webFontTxtFilters && lib.webFontTxtFilters[family] || [];
                for(var f = 0; f < txtFilters.length; ++f) {
                    txtFilters[f].updateCache();
                }
            };
// symbols:



            (lib.Fisch1 = function() {
                this.spriteSheet = ss["fisch_atlas_"];
                this.gotoAndStop(0);
            }).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



            (lib.Fisch2 = function() {
                this.spriteSheet = ss["fisch_atlas_"];
                this.gotoAndStop(1);
            }).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



            (lib.Fisch3 = function() {
                this.spriteSheet = ss["fisch_atlas_"];
                this.gotoAndStop(2);
            }).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



            (lib.Fisch7 = function() {
                this.spriteSheet = ss["fisch_atlas_"];
                this.gotoAndStop(3);
            }).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



            (lib.Fisch9 = function() {
                this.spriteSheet = ss["fisch_atlas_"];
                this.gotoAndStop(4);
            }).prototype = p = new cjs.Sprite();



            (lib.mc_blasen3 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
                this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

                // Ebene 1
                this.instance = new lib.Fisch9();
                this.instance.setTransform(-78,-55);

                this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

            }).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
            p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-78,-55,156,110);


            (lib.mc_blasen2 = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
                this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

                // Ebene 1
                this.instance = new lib.Fisch7();
                this.instance.setTransform(-78,-55);

                this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(1));

            }).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
            p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-78,-55,156,110);


            (lib.mc_anim_fisch = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
                this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

                // Ebene 1
                this.instance = new lib.Fisch1();
                this.instance.setTransform(-78,-55);

                this.instance_1 = new lib.Fisch3();
                this.instance_1.setTransform(-78,-55);

                this.instance_2 = new lib.Fisch2();
                this.instance_2.setTransform(-78,-55);

                this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.instance}]}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_1}]},9).to({state:[{t:this.instance}]},10).to({state:[{t:this.instance_1}]},10).to({state:[{t:this.instance}]},10).to({state:[{t:this.instance_2}]},10).to({state:[{t:this.instance}]},10).wait(1));

            }).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
            p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-78,-55,156,110);


// stage content:
            (lib.mainAnimation = function(mode,startPosition,loop, finished, playSound = null) {
                if (loop == null) { loop = false; } this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

                // Ebene 1
                this.instance = new lib.mc_blasen3();
                this.instance.setTransform(841,419);
                this.instance._off = true;

                this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).wait(29).to({_off:false},0).to({y:-45.9},75).wait(55).to({x:441,y:419},0).to({y:-45.9},75).wait(45).to({x:41,y:419},0).to({y:-45.9},75).to({_off:true},1).wait(1));

                // Ebene 2
                this.instance_1 = new lib.mc_blasen2();
                this.instance_1.setTransform(845,431);
                this.instance_1._off = true;

                this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_1).wait(9).to({_off:false},0).to({y:-45.9},75).wait(15).to({x:645,y:431},0).to({y:-45.9},75).wait(45).to({x:245,y:431},0).to({y:-45.9},75).to({_off:true},61).wait(1));

                // Ebene 4
                this.instance_2 = new lib.Fisch1();
                this.instance_2.setTransform(816,400);

                this.instance_3 = new lib.Fisch2();
                this.instance_3.setTransform(816,400);

                this.instance_4 = new lib.mc_anim_fisch();
                this.instance_4.setTransform(894,455);
                this.instance_4._off = true;

                this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_2}]}).to({state:[{t:this.instance_2}]},4).to({state:[{t:this.instance_3}]},5).to({state:[{t:this.instance_2}]},10).to({state:[{t:this.instance_3}]},10).to({state:[{t:this.instance_2}]},10).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},10).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[{t:this.instance_4}]},1).to({state:[]},1).wait(16).call(() => { finished(events); }));
  this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance_4).wait(49).to({_off:false},0).wait(1).to({x:890.6,y:451.8},0).wait(1).to({x:887.2,y:448.6},0).wait(1).to({x:883.8,y:445.5},0).wait(1).to({x:880.3,y:442.4},0).wait(1).to({x:876.8,y:439.5},0).wait(1).to({x:873.2,y:436.5},0).wait(1).to({x:869.5,y:433.7},0).wait(1).to({x:865.8,y:430.9},0).wait(1).to({x:862,y:428.2},0).wait(1).to({x:858.2,y:425.6},0).wait(1).to({x:854.3,y:423.1},0).wait(1).to({x:850.3,y:420.8},0).wait(1).to({x:846.3,y:418.5},0).wait(1).to({x:842.2,y:416.3},0).wait(1).to({x:838,y:414.3},0).wait(1).to({x:833.8,y:412.4},0).wait(1).to({x:829.5,y:410.6},0).wait(1).to({x:825.2,y:409.1},0).wait(1).to({x:820.8,y:407.6},0).wait(1).to({x:816.3,y:406.4},0).wait(1).to({x:811.8,y:405.3},0).wait(1).to({x:807.3,y:404.5},0).wait(1).to({x:802.7,y:403.8},0).wait(1).to({x:798.1,y:403.4},0).wait(1).to({x:793.4,y:403.2},0).wait(1).to({x:788.8},0).wait(1).to({x:784.2,y:403.4},0).wait(1).to({x:779.6,y:403.8},0).wait(1).to({x:775,y:404.5},0).wait(1).to({x:770.4,y:405.4},0).wait(1).to({x:765.9,y:406.5},0).wait(1).to({x:761.5,y:407.8},0).wait(1).to({x:757.1,y:409.2},0).wait(1).to({x:752.8,y:410.9},0).wait(1).to({x:748.5,y:412.8},0).wait(1).to({x:744.4,y:414.8},0).wait(1).to({x:740.3,y:416.9},0).wait(1).to({x:736.2,y:419.2},0).wait(1).to({x:732.3,y:421.7},0).wait(1).to({x:728.5,y:424.2},0).wait(1).to({x:724.7,y:426.9},0).wait(1).to({x:721,y:429.7},0).wait(1).to({x:717.4,y:432.6},0).wait(1).to({x:713.8,y:435.6},0).wait(1).to({x:710.3,y:438.6},0).wait(1).to({x:706.9,y:441.8},0).wait(1).to({x:703.6,y:445},0).wait(1).to({x:700.3,y:448.2},0).wait(1).to({x:697.1,y:451.6},0).wait(1).to({x:694,y:455},0).wait(11).to({x:690.6,y:451.6},0).wait(1).to({x:687.2,y:448.2},0).wait(1).to({x:683.7,y:444.8},0).wait(1).to({x:680.2,y:441.5},0).wait(1).to({x:676.6,y:438.3},0).wait(1).to({x:673,y:435.1},0).wait(1).to({x:669.3,y:432},0).wait(1).to({x:665.6,y:429},0).wait(1).to({x:661.8,y:426},0).wait(1).to({x:658,y:423.1},0).wait(1).to({x:654.1,y:420.3},0).wait(1).to({x:650.1,y:417.6},0).wait(1).to({x:646.1,y:415},0).wait(1).to({x:642,y:412.5},0).wait(1).to({x:637.8,y:410.1},0).wait(1).to({x:633.5,y:407.9},0).wait(1).to({x:629.2,y:405.8},0).wait(1).to({x:624.8,y:403.8},0).wait(1).to({x:620.3,y:402},0).wait(1).to({x:615.8,y:400.4},0).wait(1).to({x:611.2,y:399},0).wait(1).to({x:606.5,y:397.9},0).wait(1).to({x:601.8,y:396.9},0).wait(1).to({x:597.1,y:396.2},0).wait(1).to({x:592.3,y:395.7},0).wait(1).to({x:587.5,y:395.5},0).wait(1).to({x:582.7,y:395.6},0).wait(1).to({x:577.9,y:395.9},0).wait(1).to({x:573.1,y:396.5},0).wait(1).to({x:568.4,y:397.5},0).wait(1).to({x:563.7,y:398.6},0).wait(1).to({x:559.1,y:400.1},0).wait(1).to({x:554.6,y:401.8},0).wait(1).to({x:550.2,y:403.7},0).wait(1).to({x:545.9,y:405.8},0).wait(1).to({x:541.7,y:408.2},0).wait(1).to({x:537.6,y:410.7},0).wait(1).to({x:533.7,y:413.4},0).wait(1).to({x:529.8,y:416.3},0).wait(1).to({x:526.1,y:419.3},0).wait(1).to({x:522.4,y:422.5},0).wait(1).to({x:518.9,y:425.7},0).wait(1).to({x:515.4,y:429.1},0).wait(1).to({x:512.1,y:432.6},0).wait(1).to({x:508.9,y:436.1},0).wait(1).to({x:505.7,y:439.8},0).wait(1).to({x:502.7,y:443.5},0).wait(1).to({x:499.7,y:447.3},0).wait(1).to({x:496.8,y:451.1},0).wait(1).to({x:494,y:455},0).wait(11).to({x:490.6,y:451.7},0).wait(1).to({x:487.2,y:448.4},0).wait(1).to({x:483.8,y:445.2},0).wait(1).to({x:480.3,y:442},0).wait(1).to({x:476.8,y:438.9},0).wait(1).to({x:473.2,y:435.9},0).wait(1).to({x:469.5,y:432.9},0).wait(1).to({x:465.8,y:430},0).wait(1).to({x:462,y:427.2},0).wait(1).to({x:458.2,y:424.5},0).wait(1).to({x:454.3,y:421.9},0).wait(1).to({x:450.3,y:419.3},0).wait(1).to({x:446.3,y:416.9},0).wait(1).to({x:442.2,y:414.6},0).wait(1).to({x:438.1,y:412.4},0).wait(1).to({x:433.8,y:410.4},0).wait(1).to({x:429.5,y:408.5},0).wait(1).to({x:425.1,y:406.7},0).wait(1).to({x:420.7,y:405.2},0).wait(1).to({x:416.2,y:403.8},0).wait(1).to({x:411.6,y:402.6},0).wait(1).to({x:407.1,y:401.6},0).wait(1).to({x:402.4,y:400.8},0).wait(1).to({x:397.7,y:400.3},0).wait(1).to({x:393.1,y:400},0).wait(1).to({x:388.3,y:399.9},0).wait(1).to({x:383.6,y:400.1},0).wait(1).to({x:379,y:400.5},0).wait(1).to({x:374.3,y:401.2},0).wait(1).to({x:369.7,y:402.1},0).wait(1).to({x:365.1,y:403.2},0).wait(1).to({x:360.6,y:404.6},0).wait(1).to({x:356.2,y:406.2},0).wait(1).to({x:351.8,y:407.9},0).wait(1).to({x:347.6,y:409.9},0).wait(1).to({x:343.4,y:412.1},0).wait(1).to({x:339.3,y:414.4},0).wait(1).to({x:335.3,y:416.9},0).wait(1).to({x:331.4,y:419.5},0).wait(1).to({x:327.6,y:422.2},0).wait(1).to({x:323.8,y:425.1},0).wait(1).to({x:320.2,y:428.1},0).wait(1).to({x:316.6,y:431.2},0).wait(1).to({x:313.2,y:434.3},0).wait(1).to({x:309.8,y:437.6},0).wait(1).to({x:306.5,y:440.9},0).wait(1).to({x:303.2,y:444.4},0).wait(1).to({x:300.1,y:447.8},0).wait(1).to({x:297,y:451.4},0).wait(1).to({x:294,y:455},0).wait(11).to({x:290.7,y:451.7},0).wait(1).to({x:287.4,y:448.4},0).wait(1).to({x:284.1,y:445.2},0).wait(1).to({x:280.7,y:442.1},0).wait(1).to({x:277.2,y:439.1},0).wait(1).to({x:273.7,y:436.1},0).wait(1).to({x:270.1,y:433.2},0).wait(1).to({x:266.4,y:430.4},0).wait(1).to({x:262.7,y:427.7},0).wait(1).to({x:258.9,y:425},0).wait(1).to({x:255,y:422.5},0).wait(1).to({x:251,y:420.1},0).wait(1).to({x:247,y:417.8},0).wait(1).to({x:242.9,y:415.7},0).wait(1).to({x:238.8,y:413.7},0).wait(1).to({x:234.5,y:411.8},0).wait(1).to({x:230.2,y:410.1},0).wait(1).to({x:225.9,y:408.6},0).wait(1).to({x:221.4,y:407.3},0).wait(1).to({x:217,y:406.2},0).wait(1).to({x:212.4,y:405.2},0).wait(1).to({x:207.9,y:404.5},0).wait(1).to({x:203.3,y:403.9},0).wait(1).to({x:198.7,y:403.6},0).wait(1).to({x:194},0).wait(1).to({x:189.4,y:403.7},0).wait(1).to({x:184.8,y:404},0).wait(1).to({x:180.2,y:404.6},0).wait(1).to({x:175.7,y:405.4},0).wait(1).to({x:171.2,y:406.3},0).wait(1).to({x:166.7,y:407.5},0).wait(1).to({x:162.3,y:408.9},0).wait(1).to({x:157.9,y:410.4},0).wait(1).to({x:153.6,y:412.1},0).wait(1).to({x:149.4,y:414},0).wait(1).to({x:145.2,y:416},0).wait(1).to({x:141.1,y:418.1},0).wait(1).to({x:137.1,y:420.4},0).wait(1).to({x:133.2,y:422.8},0).wait(1).to({x:129.3,y:425.3},0).wait(1).to({x:125.4,y:427.9},0).wait(1).to({x:121.7,y:430.6},0).wait(1).to({x:118,y:433.4},0).wait(1).to({x:114.4,y:436.3},0).wait(1).to({x:110.8,y:439.2},0).wait(1).to({x:107.4,y:442.3},0).wait(1).to({x:103.9,y:445.3},0).wait(1).to({x:100.5,y:448.5},0).wait(1).to({x:97.2,y:451.7},0).wait(1).to({x:94,y:455},0).wait(11).to({x:90.6,y:451.9},0).wait(1).to({x:87.2,y:448.8},0).wait(1).to({x:83.8,y:445.9},0).wait(1).to({x:80.3,y:442.9},0).wait(1).to({x:76.8,y:440.1},0).wait(1).to({x:73.2,y:437.3},0).wait(1).to({x:69.5,y:434.6},0).wait(1).to({x:65.8,y:432},0).wait(1).to({x:62,y:429.4},0).wait(1).to({x:58.1,y:427},0).wait(1).to({x:54.2,y:424.6},0).wait(1).to({x:50.3,y:422.4},0).wait(1).to({x:46.2,y:420.3},0).wait(1).to({x:42.1,y:418.3},0).wait(1).to({x:38,y:416.4},0).wait(1).to({x:33.8,y:414.7},0).wait(1).to({x:29.5,y:413.1},0).wait(1).to({x:25.2,y:411.7},0).wait(1).to({x:20.8,y:410.5},0).wait(1).to({x:16.4,y:409.4},0).wait(1).to({x:11.9,y:408.5},0).wait(1).to({x:7.4,y:407.7},0).wait(1).to({x:2.9,y:407.2},0).wait(1).to({x:-1.7,y:406.9},0).wait(1).to({x:-6.2,y:406.7},0).wait(1).to({x:-10.8,y:406.8},0).wait(1).to({x:-15.3,y:407.1},0).wait(1).to({x:-19.8,y:407.5},0).wait(1).to({x:-24.3,y:408.2},0).wait(1).to({x:-28.8,y:409},0).wait(1).to({x:-33.3,y:410.1},0).wait(1).to({x:-37.6,y:411.3},0).wait(1).to({x:-42,y:412.7},0).wait(1).to({x:-46.3,y:414.2},0).wait(1).to({x:-50.5,y:415.9},0).wait(1).to({x:-54.6,y:417.8},0).wait(1).to({x:-58.7,y:419.8},0).wait(1).to({x:-62.8,y:421.9},0).wait(1).to({x:-66.7,y:424.1},0).wait(1).to({x:-70.6,y:426.5},0).wait(1).to({x:-74.5,y:429},0).wait(1).to({x:-78.2,y:431.5},0).wait(1).to({x:-81.9,y:434.2},0).wait(1).to({x:-85.5,y:436.9},0).wait(1).to({x:-89.1,y:439.8},0).wait(1).to({x:-92.6,y:442.7},0).wait(1).to({x:-96.1,y:445.7},0).wait(1).to({x:-99.4,y:448.7},0).wait(1).to({x:-102.8,y:451.8},0).wait(1).to({x:-106,y:455},0).to({_off:true},1).wait(16).call(() => { finished(events); }));

            }).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
            p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(1316,725,156,110);

        })(lib = lib||{}, images = images||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{}, this.events);

        this.animationInit = this.setupAnimations(ss, images, lib, createjs);


    }

}
```

This code is mostly generated. I had to add some code to integrate it into Angular 5 and add some events.

The Error appears when I compile with the --prod flag in Ionic. Or When I compile the file via the tsc command. ionic cordova build without --prod flag works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to install this version of zone

```
npm install --save zone.js@0.8.16
```

the problems is related to old version of zone

Comment: I'm running zone 0.8.18, doesnt seem to be related to zone. the Problem appears when I just run tsc filename.ts on the code above (the code is in filename.ts)